# Introductory C++ course assignment: Tic-Tac-Toe; Errors when setting up array

Tags: c++, arrays

So, the project is to make a tic-tac-toe game.  This is supposed to be VERY basic, as it is a fundamentals of programming course (bottom-line intro level).  I say this because any help I may receive cant be beyond my scope of knowledge or it will seem fishy.

I need the numbers displayed on the board (each space for X and O will have a place holding number of 1 - 9) to be pulled from an array I have set up.  The issue is, I can't get it to do this in the fashion I would like.

So, with the help of the comments below I have cleaned up my code a bit (this is the reason for the edits and may be why the questions and answers don't match up).

The current issue I'm having is that I don't know how to allow the user to change the number to an 'X' or an 'O'.

```
using namespace std;

int board[9] {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
};

void displayBoard(void) {
char index;
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    cout << endl;
    cout << board[index] << "|" << board[index+1] << "|";  cout << board[index+2] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+3] << "|" << board[index+4] << "|" << board[index+5] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+6] << "|" << board[index+7] << "|" << board[index+8] << endl;
    index = index + 9;

}

void playerInput(void) {



    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        cin >> board[index]
    }
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    displayBoard();


}
```

Comment: your problem might be you have 2 `board`s. I also see `index` right at the top

Comment: well not sure about the index thing but you are definitely trying to declare `board` twice, you can't do that.

Comment: Sorry - silly mistake on the double `board` declaration.  I fixed that - but regarding `index`, it is declared and then initialized but I am given errors on each line.

Comment: The variables shouldn't be globals. Use function parameters and return values.

Comment: `index(3)` is part of the C runtime library (it may depend on the platform, but it is on my version of Unix is).  If you are on some version of Unix, try doing `man index`.

Comment: @chris This helped - thank you!  Can anyone inform me how I am supposed to allow someone to change the number on the board to an X or an O?

Comment: @Eric, Ah, looks like it's just a POSIX standard function, though.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) cin >> board[index]` - the last bit should probably be `cin >> board[i];`

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 errors that will make your program fail.
1) You first declare board as a char, and then as a char[]
2) You loop over i which doesn't exist. Loop over index instead.
3) playerInput and move haven't been defined. 
4) You are assigning move's value to player input immediately after you have read in a character. And so you assign playerInput a value from the input stream but overwrite it immediately.

Aside from these technicalities, here are some stylistic tips:
cout and cin cascade. That means you can and should replace:

```
cout << board[index]; cout << "|"; cout << board[index+1] << "|";
```

with this:

```
cout << board[index] << "|" << board[index+1] << "|";
```

Additionally, you should define functions to handle your values rather than keeping them in the global scope. For now, though, I suggest focusing on understanding assignment and variable declaration.

Comment: I had to do that ugly cout thing to get rid of errors it was giving me earlier on in attempting to display the board.  I took your suggestion and fixed it, and it worked - I don't know why it didn't the first time; maybe I made different mistakes - thank you!!

I have updated my code and gotten rid of some of that stuff - I was getting ahead of myself and the clutter was confusing me in troubleshooting my current issue.  I will update my original post now.

Comment: @user3516440 - Glad I could help. I strongly recommend http://www.learncpp.com/ to help you along.